# Install local node package from file system.

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, angular6, npm-install

I have created Angular library with reference from https://medium.com/@SirMaxxx/angular-6-creating-a-shareable-control-library-6a27f0ebe5c2.

Now my dist/ars-coponent library is stored in my file system at "D:\arsprojects" location. But I have changed destination of package and stored it in root directory i.e. "D:\". Now I changed package.json and set package path as

> "ars-components": "file:../dist/ars-components",

But it isnt working and throws error as package.json not found.

I want to have this package as global and it should be possible to use this anywhere on my file system.

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a package.json file inside your module (inside dist/ars-component folder)

Comment: Yes, It does contain package.json, ng-packager created package with json file.